# Does the word "engineerical" exist?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

In a series of adjectives about fields of study such as *physical*, *mathematical*, *historical*, *philosophical* etc. how would the field of *engineering* fit in?

I looked it up in one of my Danish-English dictionaries ([Ordbogen.com](https://www.ordbogen.com/da/search#/auto/ordbogen-daen/ingeni%C3%B8rm%C3%A6ssig)) by translating a Danish equivalent word and found this translation:

> **ingeniørmæssig** <-t, -e>
>   - **engineerical**: adjektiv - It is an engineerical wonder

Apparently, the word **engineerical** exists. But I am unable to find the description of that word in any native English dictionary online, such as [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=dictionary&dictionary=en&query=engineerical) by Oxford, [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/engineerical) or [Dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/misspelling?term=engineerical). So, it doesn't seem officially recognised.

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=engineerical&oq=eng&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0j69i60j69i61l2.1449j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows - apart from some Twitter and Youtube accounts - some results that do define it:

In ["Build your own dictionary" by Meriam-Webster Word Central](http://wordcentral.com/byod/byod_search.php?term=engineerical&type=exact), a user defines it like this:

> **engineerical**
>   *Function*: adjective
>   *Definition*: having great talent as an engineer: showing great skill in engineering
>   *Example Sentence*: That engineerical construction worker built an amazing tower.

The [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Engineerical) and [Definithing](https://definithing.com/engineerical/) define it like this:

> **Engineerical**
>   Desription of a person who applies mathematical and scientific solutions to fix a problem.
>   I can not fix that machine. I am not engineerical.

This all indicates to me that this might be some "slang" word, if it exists at all. And frankly, the two shown definitions above are no entirely equivalent.

So, does this word not exist? My Danish-English dictionary is wrong? Is there an alternative I could use in the series mentioned, something that would make a sentence like the following sound proper:

> The questions on the test can be physical, mathematical, historical or **engineerical** in nature.

Comment: The adjective for engineer is engineering. Your dictionary has a mistake. An engineering question [on the exam]. The Urban Dictionary is full of crap. :) Also, engineering construction is BS to qualify a worker. Why create junk when English has a perfectly good adjective??

Comment: @Lambie Ok, so can I write a a sentence like this: *The questions on the test can be physical, mathematical, historical or **engineering** in nature.*

Comment: The questions on the exam can be about physics, math, history or engineering. Physical is not the adjective for physics. Physics is: a physics question. engineering is an adjective and the activity. Engineering can be complicated, especially chemical engineering.

Comment: I dunno Lambie: "physical" is sometimes an adjective about physics. ..."American Physical Society"; "Physical Review", "the physical sciences", "Physical Chemistry".

Answer (score 4):

It seems as if there really should be some common adjective to describe engineering things -- but, unlike so many other disciplines, there isn't.  "Engineerical" is not a word, or at least not one you would use seriously.

There are several solutions to this deficit:

1. (As per Lambie's suggestion) rewrite the sentence using nouns:

   > The questions on the exam can be about physics, math, history, or engineering
2. Use a semantically correct but stylistically awkward compound:

   > The questions on the test can be physical, mathematical, historical, or **engineering-related**
3. Use an awkward repeating term that nevertheless preserves parallelism:

   > The questions on the test can be physics-related, math-related, history-related, or **engineering-related**

---

Note that the use of "physical" to mean "physics-related" may be confusing, as the more common uses are:

> **[physical](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/physical)** (adj):
>   1 Relating to the body as opposed to the mind.
>       1.1 Involving bodily contact or activity.
>   2 Relating to things perceived through the senses as opposed to the mind; tangible or concrete.

Comment: Agree. Physics is also called “physical science“ but the word “physical“ has so many possible meetings that it is ambiguous.

Comment: And, agreed: engineerical is not really recognized as a word in standard English.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to think it's a perfectly [cromulent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisa_the_Iconoclast#Embiggen_and_cromulent) word.